# Duplicate content downloaded on page redirect

Tags: angularjs, adal.js

[image: Duplicate Content]

I am having an issue with my Angular application, with ASP.NET backend. As the image shows I am getting duplicate content being downloaded due to page redirects related to Auth. I am using Adal.js to get tokens and when it redirects back to root it re-downloads the content and doesn't clear existing content.